# How to get LatLong using TileCoordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

Above link shows how to convert lat long into Tile Coordinates (at certain zoom level); Now once I have those tile Coordinates (I need to call certain server side API with several different Tile Coordinates and their Lat/Long values).

So the question is how to convert Tile Coordinates to Lat/Long value (with reference to example shown in above mentioned link) ?

I have tried using "MercatorProjection" at other place and it works fine; but the formulas used in those cases are different than those mentioned in URL at the top.

function MercatorProjection() {.........}

MercatorProjection.prototype.fromDivPixelToLatLng = function(pixel, zoom) {.......}

MercatorProjection.prototype.fromDivPixelToSphericalMercator = function(pixel, zoom) {.......}

Comment: The question is what have you tried so far...

Comment: I am using MercatorProjection at other location but it has different formulas; tried reusing the same in this case as well but it didn't work. I have edited the question with some of its information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on below site

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

It works in both JS & C# to convert between TileCoordinates and Latitude/Longitude.